# Ionic app - how do you deep link to podcast app (for Android)?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, deep-linking

I have a podcast feed URL (an .xml file), how do I code the app such that when the user clicks the link, it will open in a podcast player?

I'm targeting Android here.

Also acceptable is a 'Share' intent where I can whitelist the apps.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, just using the [`InAppBrowser` plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/) to open an '.xml' link does the trick.

Specifically, Castbox and Podcast Addict are both registered to show up in the 'Share With' menu when I open an .xml link.